# Hibernate - map multiple enums Set in query

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I have following tables:

```
user
- id BIGINT
- name VARCHAR
```

```
user_roles
- id BIGINT
- user_id BIGINT - FK TO USER
- name VARCHAR (name of the role)
```

so by using this we can assign multiple roles to user. In Java there is `UserRole` enum. How can I load in Hibernate user records with assigned roles?

I have following code

```
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=UserRole.class)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name="user_role")
    @Column(name="name")
    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }
    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles= userRoles;
    }
```

and I make the query like this:

```
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> queryRoot = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
        queryRoot.join("userRoles", JoinType.LEFT);

        TypedQuery<User> query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery);

        return query.getResultList();
```

Query runs but when I try to access the roles Set it says

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. You will have to write a class that implements the AttributeConverter interface that can be used to convert entity attribute state into database column representation and back again. Reference: https://memorynotfound.com/mapping-enum-types-hibernate-example/

Comment: not sure whether this is the right link, it is easy for me to store enum if it is a table column on a particular table, but here I need to assigne multiple enums to single entity.